#  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid cursor state in my jsp page

Tags: jsp, jdbc

i wish to create a table in which the first 3 columns are plain text but the 4th column is a column of text areas and the last column is a column of drop down lists.
all the input given in these form elements is to be sent to a separate jsp page where iit will be updated in the database.
here is the code i wrote

```
    <form name="input" action="UpdateSMCFO.jsp" method="post">

    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>Dist. Code</th>
    <th>Cons. No.</th>
    <th>Consumer Details</th>
    <th>Verification by FO</th>
    <th>Remarks by SO</th>

    </tr>
    <%
    int r=0;
    while (rs.next()) {r++;
                   }
    for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
                   {
    out.println("<TR>");
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    if(i>=0 && i<=2)
    {
        out.println("<TD>"+rs.getString(i+1)+"</TD>");
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
    out.println("<TD><input type=\"text\" name=\"FOVerification\""+String.valueOf(j)+"/></TD>");
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("<TD><select name=\"SORemarks\""+String.valueOf(j)+">");
        out.println("<option value=\"Please Specify\">Please Specify</option>");
        out.println("<option value=\"Genuine Customer\">Genuine Customer</option>");
        out.println("<option value=\"MC\">MC-To be blocked</option>");
        out.println("</select></TD>");
    }
    }              
    out.println("</TR>");

                  }
%>
</table>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

 </form>
```

i am very sure this is not the way to handle the table elements but this is all i could come up with.
please give me any ideas in the scope of jsp and html only.
now, i only started learning jsp a week ago so i am very new to the concepts.

this is the stack trace:

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Comment: I'm not sure what you're concretely asking, but I can at least suggest to throw away that book/tutorial you're currently using. It's only teaching you old school practices. Put your mouse above the `[jsp]` tag which you've placed on the question until a black info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: i have posted the stack trace... please help me resolve this error.. thank you

Comment: you are using double quotes within an string in a wrong way , you missed to put '\' character to in the string while using '"'

Comment: oH! i cannot believe i was that stupid. thank you so much! 
but now i get a different error! posting it too. please help.

Answer (score 0):

got it! 
i just tried to understand it with the name of the exception: INvalid cursor state..

so my sql cursor state was invalid at line 34!

changed it to:

```
    while (rs.next()) {

    out.println("<TR>");
    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    if(i>=0 && i<=2)
    {
        out.println("<TD>"+rs.getString(i+1)+"</TD>");
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
    out.println("<TD><input type=\"text\" name=\"FOVerification\""+String.valueOf(r)+"/></TD>");
    }
           else if(i==4)
    {
        out.println("<TD><select name=\"SORemarks\""+String.valueOf(r)+">");
        out.println("<option value=\"Please Specify\">Please Specify</option>");
        out.println("<option value=\"Genuine Customer\">Genuine Customer</option>");
        out.println("<option value=\"MC\">MC-To be blocked</option>");
        out.println("</select></TD>");
    }
    }
    out.println("</TR>");
    r++;
                  }
```

and it worked! :)